# preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset 27 on line number 25

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am writing up some PHP code. In this code, I am running a for loop within a for loop to iterate over an array, then to iterate over the characters in the current string in the array.

I then want to do preg_match() on the current string to see if it matches a rather ling RegEx.

```
preg_match('/[ \f\n\r\t\v\x{00a0}\x{1680}\x{180e}\x{2000-}\x{200a}\x{2028}\x{2029}\x{202f}\x{205f}\x{3000}\x{feff}]/', $input[$i][$j])
```

But I keep on receiving the following error:

> WARNING preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or
>   \o{} is too large at offset 27 on line number 25

Comment: What did you plan to match with `\x{2000-}`? I guess it is a typo. Check [`[ \f\n\r\t\v\x{00a0}\x{1680}\x{180e}\x{2000}-\x{200a}\x{2028}\x{2029}\x{202f}\x{205f}\x{3000}\x{feff}]`](https://regex101.com/r/gV6vN2/2). Does it work?

Comment: If this is a typo, please remove the question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add UTF-8 parsing, you are not in UFT8 mode. Add the `u` parameter.

```
preg_match('/[ \f\n\r\t\v\x{00a0}\x{1680}\x{180e}\x{2000-}\x{200a}\x{2028}\x{2029}\x{202f}\x{205f}\x{3000}\x{feff}]/u', $input[$i][$j]);
```

Also, i'd like to emphasize too that you have a typo. `\x{2000-}` should be `\x{2000}` or `\x{2000}-`:

```
preg_match('/[ \f\n\r\t\v\x{00a0}\x{1680}\x{180e}\x{2000}\x{200a}\x{2028}\x{2029}\x{202f}\x{205f}\x{3000}\x{feff}]/u', $input[$i][$j]);
```

Comment: If you see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions I have copied the RegEx from "\s" it shows the unicode character (\u200-) with a hyphen at the end of it, which I thought looked weird, but I can't work out if it should actually be like that or not

Comment: @Timothy Actually, that is a *range*. \u2000​-\u200a​ means, every character in the range of \u2000 till \u200a. So it has to be `\x{2000}-\x{200a}`

Comment: Actually... it doesn't -_- I tried even stripping it back to ```\x{2000}\x{2001}\x{2002}\x{2003}\x{2004}\x{2005}\x{2006}\x{2007}\x{2008}\x{2009}\x{200a}``` and it's giving me the same error :/

Comment: @Timothy The typo is not the issue of your error, did you add the `u` after the last `/` like i told first?

Comment: @Timothy: You use the wrong documentation. That one is for JavaScript. You should read this instead: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php